# Using Ternary Operators with Material UI (useMediaQuery)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to UI development and I am working on a web project. 
I need to change the style on different screen sizes but I am using Material UI components and can't use the CSS media queries.

const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');

```
            <MenuLogoButton edge="start">
              <img 
                src={Logo} 
                className = {matches ? classes.mobilelogo : classes.logo} 
              />
            </MenuLogoButton>
```

I'm sure you can guess what I am trying to do from the code, I am trying to get the logo to change its size on smaller screens

But the ternary operation doesn't seem to work, and I am here to learn why. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint and see what is the op of the ternary operation. Also Is there any error in the console?

Comment: It looks like you have the condition reverse of what it should be. `matches` will be true for widths of 600px and greater, but that is the case where you are using `classes.mobilelogo`.